# UITableViewCell - overlapping with previous cells contents

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have this wierd problem with my table

1. i Have about 20 cells to display
2. Each cell is about 84px in height
3. When i click no the cell, i have set a background colour
4. The first 4 cells are ok, but when i scroll down and click on the 5th cell, the content of each cell starts to overlap with some other content, usually content from 1st 4 cells.

I belive its some cell reusability or drawing issue. Am not sure how to solve it, i have checked through my code, but i am not changing the cell's content on touch.

Here is my code and will add some pics too
[image: Cell with overlapped content]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 104;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     return [stores count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 250, 30);
    CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(6, 42, 220, 20);    
    CGRect Label3Frame = CGRectMake(6, 62, 220, 20);        
    CGRect Label4Frame = CGRectMake(240,56, 70, 12);            

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }else{
        // a cell is being recycled, remove the old edit field (if it contains one of our tagged edit fields)
        UIView *viewToCheck = nil;
        viewToCheck = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        if (!viewToCheck) {
            [viewToCheck removeFromSuperview];
            DebugLog(@"View removed");
        }       
    }
    //cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgView];    
    NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
    UILabel *lblTemp;
    [[cell contentView] clearsContextBeforeDrawing];

    //Line 1

    lblTemp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: Label1Frame];
    lblTemp.tag=1;
    lblTemp.text=[[stores objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:0] ;
    lblTemp.numberOfLines=2;
    lblTemp.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    lblTemp.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    lblTemp.minimumFontSize=12;
    lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];  
    [lblTemp release];
    //Line 2
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Frame];
    lblTemp.tag = 2;
    lblTemp.text=[[stores objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:1];   
    lblTemp.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor grayColor ];
    lblTemp.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblTemp.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    lblTemp.minimumFontSize=12;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];  
    [lblTemp release];

    //Line 3    
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label3Frame];
    lblTemp.tag = 3;
    lblTemp.text=[[stores objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:2];
    lblTemp.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor grayColor ];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];      
    [lblTemp release];
    //Phone button
    UIButton *phoneButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,16,30,30)];
    [phoneButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [phoneButton setTag:row];
    [phoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dialNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:phoneButton];
    //ANnotation button
    UIButton *annotation=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(274,16,30,30)]; 
    [annotation setTag:row];
    [annotation setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [annotation addTarget:self action:@selector(openMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [cell.contentView addSubview:annotation];   
    [annotation release];
    //Distance label
    //Line 3    
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label4Frame];
    lblTemp.tag = 4;
    lblTemp.text=[[stores objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:5];   
    lblTemp.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblTemp.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor grayColor ];
    [lblTemp setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];      
    [phoneButton release];
    [lblTemp release];  
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];   
    for(UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        }
    }
    //UITableViewCell *cell1;       
    //NSString *row=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    svm = [[storesMapView alloc] initWithNibName:@"storesMapView" bundle:nil];
    [svm initWithXML:stores:indexPath.row];
    CGRect theFrame = svm.view.frame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    svm.view.frame = theFrame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
    theFrame.size=CGSizeMake(320,355);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    svm.view.frame = theFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [subView addSubview:svm.view];
    backButton.hidden=NO;


}
```

Comment: You should really be building cells like this in a nib, rather than making everything in cellForRow.

Comment: You can see the answer here too. Clearly explained.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999300/labels-in-custom-cell-overlaps

Comment: i have the same problem but my subviews are not instantiated in code but come from a storyboard. if a remove the subviews they are all gone. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out with some trial and error; if this can help some one

In cellforRowAtIndexPath i tried to clear all the cells subview before drawing the cell

```
//TRY TO REMOVE ALL CONTENT
    for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

I would be happy if someone can point me to some easier way

Thanks

Comment: The easier way is to do this is to place all dynamically added views into one common subview and remove all this view's subviews in UITableViewCell's prepareForReuse method

Comment: @NikolayKasyanov's suggestion above is the correct place to do this.

Answer (score 7):

**You can use**

```
[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

If the cell in not nil, the above code will reduce the time for using the for loop similar to this

```
for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews])
    [eachView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue.I also  had composed tableView with labels.And when I scroll it down the contents got overlapped.But it got solved simply by editing one statement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a  bit late, but I had a similar issue where UILabels created for a cell were still part of the cell when it was reused.  So each successive update of the tableview created another UILabel on top of the existing one.  I moved the creation of the Labels into the if condition as below and it resolved my issue.  Hope it helps someone else.  Also note no release as I am using ARC.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 

    {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cityText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
    cityText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
    cityText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    cityText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    regionText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 20)];
    regionText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
    regionText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    regionText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting **nil** to label text  on UITableViewCell subclass 's method  **prepareForReuse()** solved my problem -

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.label1.text = nil
    self.label2.text = nil
    ....
}
```

Shared if it helps anyone!