# labels in custom cell overlaps

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have customized the cell with four labels, initially it looks fine but when I scroll and then select a cell labels from another row overlaps. here is my code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                            reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
 NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIcon] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cellImage=[UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];

cell.imageView.image=cellImage;

UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 140, 20)];
labelOne.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
[labelOne release];

UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 10, 140, 20)];
labelTwo.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[newPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
[labelTwo release];



UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 30, 140, 20)];
label3.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label3];
[label3 release];


UILabel *label4 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 30, 140, 20)];
label4.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[oldPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label4];
[label4 release];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is you allocated the labels in (else part)outside of the if condition `if(cell==nil)`. You should only create the labels once, when the cell is first created.

When we run the code the control checks whether the cell is nil or have any values. If we allocate the label in else part every time (while scrolling also) you are creating a new label every time. If we allocate it in if condition, the label is only allocated once for each cell and we just update the text value when scrolling.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{ 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                            reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIcon] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cellImage=[UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];

cell.imageView.image=cellImage;

UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 140, 20)];
labelOne.tag = 100;
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
[labelOne release];

UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 10, 140, 20)];
labelTwo.tag = 101;
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
[labelTwo release];

}

UILabel *labelOne = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
labelOne.text = [dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *labelTwo = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
labelTwo.text = [newPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this code is better than the code in the question, that would make this answer worthy of an upvote.

Comment: it works... could you please explain whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Mr.NoviceDeveloper and Mr.Jrturton. The mistake is you allocated the labels in (else part)outside of the if condition 'if(cell==nil)'. When we run the code the control checks whether the cell is nil or have any values. If we allocate the label in else part every time (while scrolling also) the label is allocating and get the values from an array. If we allocate it in if condition, only once the Label is allocate for each cell and get values from an array. Sorry for my poor english. It is clear? Thanks.

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M I've moved that into your answer and cleaned it up a bit. Thanks for adding that, it has made a much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this following code snippet after

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

for (UIView * subView in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
 [subView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Hope it  will Help You :)