# When Scroll down/up, text of uitextfield in uitableview has been reset iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using TPAvoidKeyBoard at [here](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). And i used below code to create UItextfield in uitableview (TPAvoidKeyBoard class) but when I scroll down/up, text of UITextfield on top/ bottom has been reset. Please give some advice to solve that issue. Thanks in advance

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"menubackcolor.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];


    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6,80, 25)];
            [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            label1.text = @"First Name";
           // cell.accessoryView =label1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

            self.firstNametxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,5, 200, 30)];
            self.firstNametxt.tag =1;
            self.firstNametxt.placeholder = @"First Name";
            [self.firstNametxt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            self.firstNametxt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.firstNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"FirstName"] ];
            cell.accessoryView = self.firstNametxt;

            //[cell.contentView addSubview:self.firstNametxt];


        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1){
            UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6,60, 25)];
            [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            label1.text = @"Last Name";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

            self.lastNametxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,5, 200, 30)];
            self.lastNametxt.tag =2;
            self.lastNametxt.placeholder = @"Last Name";
            [self.lastNametxt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            self.lastNametxt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.lastNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"LastName" ]];
            cell.accessoryView = self.lastNametxt;
            // [cell.contentView addSubview:self.lastNametxt];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 2){
            UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6,60, 25)];
            [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            label1.text = @"Nick Name";
            //cell.accessoryView =label1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];


            self.name_txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,5, 200, 30)];
            self.name_txt.tag =3;
            self.name_txt.placeholder = @"Nick Name";
            [self.name_txt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            self.name_txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.name_txt.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"Nickname"] ];
            cell.accessoryView = self.name_txt;
            //[cell.contentView addSubview:self.name_txt];

        }

        if(indexPath.row ==4)
        {
            UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6,60, 25)];
            [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            label1.text = @"Birthdate";
            //cell.accessoryView =label1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

            self.birthdate_txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 7, 200, 30)];
            self.birthdate_txt.tag =4;
            self.birthdate_txt.placeholder = @"ddmmyy";
            self.birthdate_txt.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [self.birthdate_txt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            self.birthdate_txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            self.birthdate_txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.birthdate_txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d/%02d/%d",day,month,year];
            cell.accessoryView = self.birthdate_txt;
            //[cell.contentView addSubview:self.birthdate_txt];
        }
 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you should create the subviews of the cell only when the cell is created. Here you are re-using the cell but creating the subviews each time.

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"menubackcolor.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6,80, 25)];
            [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            label1.text = @"First Name";
           // cell.accessoryView =label1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

            self.firstNametxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,5, 200, 30)];
            self.firstNametxt.tag =1;
            self.firstNametxt.placeholder = @"First Name";
            [self.firstNametxt setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            self.firstNametxt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

            cell.accessoryView = self.firstNametxt;

            //[cell.contentView addSubview:self.firstNametxt];


        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1){
....
}
}

if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
self.firstNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"FirstName"] ];
}
}
....
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still same.That means it still reset when srcoll .

Comment: How do you fetch the text>

Comment: I fetch text in uitableview as below:  if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            
            self.firstNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"FirstName"] ];
                    }
        if (indexPath.row == 1){
            
            self.lastNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo  objectForKey:@"LastName" ]];
        }

Comment: And when click on Save button, I save data to NSDictionary as below:updateuserInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  self.firstNametxt.text, USER_FIRST_NAME_TAG,
                                  self.lastNametxt.text, USER_LAST_NAME_TAG,
                                  GenderString, USER_GENDER_TAG,
                                  self.name_txt.text, USER_NICK_NAME_TAG,

Comment: You are storing the value with key USER_FIRST_NAME_TAG while you are fetching it using @"FirstName". Use the same key.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm fetching by using: self.firstNametxt.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUserInfo objectForKey:@"FirstName"] ]; 
dicUserInfo is NSDictionary has objectkey USER_FIRST_NAME_TAG

Comment: I define: #define USER_FIRST_NAME_TAG  @"FirstName"

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you should do

1. Don't create cell subview each time. Use the concept of cell reusability.
2. You can use Custom Cell.
3. Or you can avoid this type of mismatch with using subview's tag property.

Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999300/labels-in-custom-cell-overlaps)