# Custom cells getting replaced with other cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I created a custom cell. When I use these custom cells in table view My cells getting replaced.I created about 10 sections in the table view in which each section contains 1 row. I am using Custom Cells for all 10 sections. When I scroll the view, the last 4 cells are replaced with top cells. I am using ReuseIdentifier but they are still getting replaced. Any Ideas to fix this? Thanks!

This is my CustomCell Code!

```
-(UITableViewCell *)returnCellForBirthdayDetails:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellForBirthdayDetails"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellToAddDetails" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;
        //        customCell = nil;
    }

    return  cell;
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [customCellTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextField *textField = nil;

    if( customCell )
    {
        textField = (UITextField *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    }

    return textField;
}
```

and Here I am calling custom cells in the tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     addCustomCell  = [[CustomCellToAddDetailsController alloc] init];

    switch (indexPath.section) 
    {
        case 0:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"FirstName";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"FirstName";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"LastName";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"LastName";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"Dob";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Dob";
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.inputView = dp;
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.inputAccessoryView=toolBarForTableView;
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"Address";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Address";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"City";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Enter City";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 5:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"State";    
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Enter State";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 6:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"Email";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Email";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
        case 7:
            cell = [addCustomCell returnCellForBirthdayDetails:tableView];
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.text = @"Phone";
            addCustomCell.customCellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            addCustomCell.customCellTextField.placeholder = @"Enter MobileNo";
            [delegate.fieldArray addObject:addCustomCell];
            break;
    }
    return cell;
    [addCustomCell release];

}
```

Please let me know what mistake I am making. Thanks!!

Comment: @kiran try to append some code with question, it'd good..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different reuseIdentifier for each cell. When you use the same identifier, then the tableview will just grab any available cell with this identifier (in your case it's grabbing the top ones since they are no longer in use).

Edit:
You can use the same identifier (and you should) for cells that are identical in everything except text/image. Then you can call a 'configureCell' method where you set the text/image/etc for each cell.

Comment: :Here i am using one custom cell for all the sections in tale view. Then how can i use different identifier for that each?Do u mean i need to create 10 custom cells ?

Comment: You either need to create 10 custom cells, or you need to implement functionality in the tableView delegate's `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method that configures the cell with the proper information each time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

It is getting replaced because your cells are being reused.

1. Either you have to create new cells every time.(Don't use dequeueReusableIdentifier. Or use different identifiers for each cell. It is inefficient).
2. Clean up the cell every time before drawing it. (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4790942/641062))