# Weird behavior of UISegmentedControl in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm making an app with a UITableView that uses ELCTextfieldCells. For some cells I set a UISegmentedControl on top of it and disable UITextField. "A picture is worth a thousand words", so here's the screenshot of what I get when I slide to that UITableView:

[image]

And after moving that cell from the screen and putting it back(basically reloading) I get the following:

[image]

So there are 2 problems:

- UISegmentedControl is not visible when the view appears for the first time;
- The values of that UISegmentedControl are written in the cell somewhere on top;

Some code that anyhow affects these cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([[self.tableViewCellValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]rangeOfString:@"Gender"].location != NSNotFound || [[self.tableViewCellValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]rangeOfString:@"Still Active Employee"].location != NSNotFound) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellWithSegmentedControl";
    ELCTextfieldCell *cell = (ELCTextfieldCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ELCTextfieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
    if ([cell.leftLabel.text rangeOfString:@"Gender"].location != NSNotFound) {
        segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil]];
    } else {
        segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", nil]];
    }
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(215, 6, cell.rightTextField.frame.size.width, cell.rightTextField.frame.size.height - 10);
    segmentedControl.tag = 26;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [cell bringSubviewToFront:segmentedControl];
    cell.rightTextField.text = @"";
    cell.rightTextField.enabled = NO;
    return cell;
  }
  //checks and other stuff for other cells
}

-(void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Nothing implemented here yet");
}
```

Any help on how can I fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it is the problem of reusing cells. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9598341/641062) would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are giving `cell.rightTextField.frame.size.height - 10`

may be thats why it is going up, have you checked the height ?

Comment: thanks, found where the error is. At the moment of setting the frame to the UISegmentedControl the frame of the rightTextField was `0, 0, 0, 0`, so the frame of the UISegmentedControl became `215, -4, 0, 10`. And that also explains why it wasn't visible on first load.